# ASP.NET, C# y SQL SERVER 2016 convertir string a operador ( ">=" a >= )

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo una aplicación web donde tengo mi histórico de ventas de mis sucursales. El problema es que tengo una búsqueda/filtrado por criterios dentro de un rango y entre la aplicación y mi base de datos no sé cómo interpretar los valores para que se puedan convertir en operadores. Regularmente todo lo manejo por stored procedure pero si fuera necesario hacer la query en la app no tendría problema. Debo aclarar que en la vista los operadores los tengo representados por dropdowlist de texto (ejemplo: "(>)  Mayor que") y de valor o value (ejemplo: ">").

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como lo dices en tu enunciado debes sustituir tus opciones por un armado manual  del query donde sea mayor que y tendras que agregar esa condicion en tu  query.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Siempre puedes montar una query dinámica, que realice tu select en el procedure. Un ejemplo simple puede ser tal que:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.venta
(id        INT
 PRIMARY KEY, 
 sucursal  INT, 
 encargado INT, 
 folio     INT, 
 fotos     INT, 
 importe   INT
);
GO
-- Creación de la tabla de ejemplo
INSERT INTO dbo.venta
(id, sucursal, encargado, folio,fotos,importe)
VALUES
(1,1,1 ,1,0,10),
(2,1,2 ,0,0,20),
(3,2,1 ,3,0,30),
(4,2,4 ,1,1,16),
(5,1,1 ,2,5,37),
(6,1,10,1,9,25);
-- Inserto unas filas de ejemplo
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_VentaFiltrar 
(
 @SUCURSAL INT=-1,  -- parámetros por defecto
 @FOLIODESDE INT =1,
 @PARAMFOLIODESDE INT =0,
 @FOLIOHASTA INT =23,
 @PARAMFOLIOHASTA INT=1
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @OPER1 NVARCHAR(2);
-- si el parametro es de tal condición "número mágico"
-- También podría ser directamente el string >= o comparar con "Mayor (que)" o lo que envíes
IF @PARAMFOLIODESDE = 0 
    SET @OPER1 = N'>';
ELSE IF @PARAMFOLIODESDE = 1
    SET @OPER1 = N'<';
ELSE IF @PARAMFOLIODESDE = 2
SET @OPER1 = N'>=';
ELSE IF @PARAMFOLIODESDE = 3
SET @OPER1 = N'<=';
ELSE 
SET @OPER1 = N'=';
/* TAMBIEN PODRÍAS INCLUIR is null etc.... */
DECLARE @OPER2 NVARCHAR(2);
IF @PARAMFOLIOHASTA = 0 
   SET @OPER2 = N'>';
ELSE IF @PARAMFOLIOHASTA = 1
   SET @OPER2 = N'<';
ELSE IF @PARAMFOLIOHASTA = 2
   SET @OPER2 = N'>=';
ELSE IF @PARAMFOLIOHASTA = 3
    SET @OPER2 = N'<=';
ELSE 
   SET @OPER2 = N'=';

DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @QUERY = N'
SELECT * FROM dbo.venta
WHERE
(sucursal = '+CAST(@SUCURSAL AS nvarchar(10)) + N' OR '+ CAST(@SUCURSAL AS     nvarchar(10)) +N' = -1)
AND
FOLIO '+@OPER1 + CAST(@FOLIODESDE AS Nvarchar(10)) +N'
AND 
FOLIO '+@OPER2 + CAST(@FOLIOHASTA AS Nvarchar(10)) +N';';

--PRINT @QUERY
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY
END
GO
-- Un ejemplo de consumo
EXEC sp_VentaFiltrar 
 @SUCURSAL = -1,
 @FOLIODESDE  =2,
 @PARAMFOLIODESDE  =2,
 @FOLIOHASTA  =5,
 @PARAMFOLIOHASTA =1
```

Existen muchas posibilidades de hacer esto, y de mejorarlo, ya que el código, solo pretende enseñarte una pequeña vía para poder realizarlo.
Si sigues este camino, tienes que contemplar todas las causísticas, por ejemplo que si en el primer desplegable existe un igual, el segundo parámetro tiene que ser como el primero, o algo del estilo.

Además un número indeterminado de parámetros en una tabla muy grande, puede generar un plan de ejecución, no óptimo.

[image: Resultados]